# How to partition array of integers to even and odd?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-partitioning

I want to partition an array (eg `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`), first partition should keep even values, second odd values (example result: `[2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7]`).

I managed to resolve this problem twice with built-in `Array.prototype` methods. First solution uses `map` and `sort`, second only `sort`.

I would like to make a third solution which uses a sorting algorithm, but I don't know what algorithms are used to partition lists. I'm thinking about bubble sort, but I think it is used in my second solution (`array.sort((el1, el2)=>(el1 % 2 - el2 % 2))`)... I looked at [`quicksort`](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/11/27/computer-science-in-javascript-quicksort/), but I don't know where to apply a check if an integer is even or odd...

What is the best (linear scaling with array grow) algorithm to perform such task in-place with keeping order of elements?

Comment: Any sort is at best `O(nlogn)`, so if you want linear scaling, those aren't the best option

Comment: `sort`??? Have you tried using `filter`?

Comment: Why in-place? What purpose is served by that?

Comment: Why downvote? What is wrong with my question?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in-place, I think only purpose is to make it harder (my question is a homework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are insisting on an in-place approach instead of the trivial standard `return [arr.filter(predicate), arr.filter(notPredicate)]` approach, that can be easily and efficiently achieved using two indices, running from both sides of the array and swapping where necessary:

```
function partitionInplace(arr, predicate) {
    var i=0, j=arr.length;
    while (i<j) {
        while (predicate(arr[i]) && ++i<j);
        if (i==j) break;
        while (i<--j && !predicate(arr[j]));
        if (i==j) break;
        [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
        i++;
    }
    return i; // the index of the first element not to fulfil the predicate
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same logic as my answer? Won't this change the relative order of items in the partitions? That is, if given [1,3,2,4], the resulting array will be [4,2,3,1]?

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, it's the same idea, only my implementation works with arbitrary predicates, returns the position at which the array is partitioned, and has therefore much more complicated code :-) Indeed the swap change the relative order, but I'm pretty sure that there is no algorithm that does achieve a stable reordering in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space complexity.

Comment: I think you're right that there isn't an O(n), O(1) solution that's stable. Reminds me of the joke(?): Fast, Cheap, Good: pick two.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in-place in O(n) time pretty easily. Start the even index at the front, and the odd index at the back. Then, go through the array, skipping over the first block of even numbers.

When you hit an odd number, move backwards from the end to find the first even number. Then swap the even and odd numbers.

The code looks something like this:

```
var i;
var odd = n-1;
for(i = 0; i < odd; i++)
{
    if(arr[i] % 2 == 1)
    {
        // move the odd index backwards until you find the first even number.
        while (odd > i && arr[odd] % 2 == 1)
        {
            odd--;
        }
        if (odd > i)
        {
            var temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[odd];
            arr[odd] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Pardon any syntax errors. Javascript isn't my strong suit.

Note that this won't keep the same relative order. That is, if you gave it the array `[1,2,7,3,6,8]`, then the result would be `[8,2,6,3,7,1]`. The array is partitioned, but the odd numbers aren't in the same relative order as in the original array.

Comment: While this is efficient, I thought part of the objective was to make it a stable partition, since the OP specified in the example that the output should maintain the same order as the input within each of the partitions.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: I don't see where OP specifically says that the output should be stable. His example shows a stable arrangement, but there's nothing that says it must be stable. Point taken, though: this is not stable. I'll update my answer with that information.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts,  thanks, It should keep partition order like You say. Sorry  Jim I didn't write it explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

```
let evens = arr.filter(i=> i%2==0);
let odds = arr.filter(i=> i%2==1);
let result = evens.concat(odds);
```

I believe that's O(n). Have fun.

EDIT:
Or if you really care about efficiency:

```
let evens, odds = []
arr.forEach(i=> {
if(i%2==0) evens.push(i); else odds.push(i);
});
let result = evens.concat(odds);
```

Comment: Meh, we can cut half that overhead. (Nor is this in-place, see the end of the answer.)

Comment: Still not in-place, as the question clearly calls for. Still produces two temporary arrays in addition to the third final one. *(not my dv; I understand it, but wouldn't do it)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `i` is a reserved keyword for `index`, isn't it?

Comment: @kind: No, not at all. It can be whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score -2):

```
Array.prototype.getEvenOdd= function (arr) {
    var result = {even:[],odd:[]};
    if(arr.length){
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] % 2 = 0)
            result.odd.push(arr[i]);
        else
            result.even.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    return result ;
};
```